# Flutter - The getter 'build' isn't defined in a superclass of 'CustomButton'

Tags: flutter, inheritance, build, widget, superclass

I'm trying to create a custom button widget in Flutter. It should be based on the ElevatedButton widget. Somehow I get this Error message:

*The getter 'build' isn't defined in a superclass of 'CustomButton'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'build' in a superclass.*

But the superclass definitely has the build method. Here's the code:

```
class CustomButton extends ElevatedButton {
  @override
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  const CustomButton({required this.onPressed, required this.child})
      : super(onPressed: onPressed, child: child);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          buttonTheme: Theme.of(context).buttonTheme.copyWith(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)))),
      child: Builder(builder: super.build),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Cant find any `build` method on `ElevatedButton`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `build` method in `ElevatedButton`, which extends `ButtonStyleButton`. `ButtonStyleButton` is s StatefulWidget, which has no `build` method neither.